# How to reconcile itertools.product with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have the code shared at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185129/157474. And I'm trying to use multiprocessing. I used such a remodeling:

```
count=1   
def foo(i):

    global count
    dobre2=[]

    if tuple(reversed(i)) >= tuple(i):           
       a = ['v{}'.format(x%2) for x in i] 
       # the rest of the code

    return dodane_pary
```

And:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = mul.Pool(4)
    result = pool.map(foo, itertools.product(tuple(range(2)), repeat=4))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print (result)
```

Instead:

```
count=1
dobre2=[]

for i in itertools.product(tuple(range(2)), repeat=4): 
    if tuple(reversed(i)) >= tuple(i):
       a = ['v{}'.format(x%2) for x in i]
       # the rest of the code
```

Expected output:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 1], [0, 2, 3, 8], [0, 2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 8, 7], [6, 1, 3, 8], [2, 3, 5, 9], [11, 0, 2, 3], [11, 4, 1, 5], [7, 1, 5, 9]]
```

Unfortunately, I do not receive the expected exit, but the list in this form:

```
[[[0, 2, 4, 6]], [[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 1]], [[0, 2, 1, 4]], [[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 1], [0, 2, 3, 5]], [[0, 2, 1, 4]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3]], [[0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 1], [0, 2, 3, 5], [0, 7, 9, 8]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1], [1, 4, 3, 7]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1], [1, 4, 3, 7]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1], [1, 4, 3, 7]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1], [1, 4, 3, 7]], [[0, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [0, 5, 7, 3], [5, 0, 2, 1], [1, 4, 3, 7], [3, 7, 5, 9]]]
```

In addition, every time I start the program, I get some changed results as if the processes were randomly assigned. What am I doing wrong? How to synchronize it well?

Comment: what is dodane_pary? Your foo is not functional in this code.

Comment: Cześć. spójrz na link u góry mojego postu. jest cały kod uruchomiony. `dodane_pary` to lista, do której dobrymi wartościami dodaje się w kolejnych krokach.

Comment: You never say In what way the output you're getting is wrong. What needs reconciling?

Comment: @martineau how is it? because I do not understand. they are bad because they are different than expected, which I gave in the description.

Comment: OK, but _how_ is it different? What's the problem?

Comment: firstly, as you can see, sub-lists are created in the sub-lists, and secondly, the results should be created in the same order in terms of individual sub-lists. but at my, the results are like from different stages, randomly, unconnected, as if the processes were not synchronized.

Comment: THe whole idea of multiprocessing is to allow multiple processes to run concurrently. This implies that the results may be generated in a random order if the tasks do not all take the same amount of time to execute.

Comment: therefore I have more and more doubts whether my algorithm can be parallelized.

Comment: because I have some kind of recursiveness. for example, step 6 can not take place if there were no previous ones in the right order.

Comment: It's quite possible that your algorithm does not lend itself to concurrency. You may need to step back and see if you can come up with a way to do whatever you're doing that _is_ conducive to parallelization.